# Freeze the last viewed position on jquery load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I load a table via jquery, and i set width and height for the table with overflow:auto.  Whenever the table reloads, it comes to the top.  I need to stay where i am seeing the datas even after the table reloads.

here we go for details,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $('#livestatus').load('live.php');
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Html

```
<div align="center" id="livestatus"></div>
```

In live.php, it will generate dynamic datas...

```
<table><tr><td>datas</td></tr>
<tr><td>datas</td></tr>
<tr><td>datas</td></tr>
<tr><td>datas</td></tr>
<tr><td>datas</td></tr>
.
.
.
<tr><td>datas</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrollTop on the element you're loading into before you make the request to save the position of the overflowed div, then use a callback in load to set the scroll back to what it was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
         var scrollCache = $('#livestatus').scrollTop();
         $('#livestatus').load('live.php', function(){
              $('#livestatus').scrollTop(scrollCache);
         });
     }, 2000);
 </script>
```

Cheers! 
Andrew

Comment: Hi, Andrew.  Thanks for answering.  I am sorry, that the code doesn't make any changes.  
whenever jquery load live.php, table goes top.

Comment: Oops! You're right. Note I omitted a # in the second call to scrollTop by accident, I will edit the code.

Comment: Since I don't know anything else about your app, I'm not going to assume you don't have another race condition in the 2 seconds, so here's the API for making overflowing divs move:
https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: The variable ScrollCache always getting the value '0' even there is scrolling in the table.  Shall we use anyother div id to get scrollTop() value.  Do you get any idea..  Is it suitable to get scrolltop value from table id..

Comment: Use whatever div is the one scrolling. Try doing the read version of the call in the JS console on different elements: $(someSelectorString).scrollTop(); until you get a nonzero, then use that for my two operations that call scrollTop.